How to determine the best components for an example application circuits depicted in a saw resonator datasheet
There is an example application circuit for what I am trying to create in the datasheet of a SAW resonator, but it does not contain passive part values or how to determine them.
The example in question is "Typical Low-Power Transmitter Application
https://www.rfmi.co/pdf/Datasheet/ro3144e.pdf

There aren't too many degrees of freedom as we expect C1 in series with C2 is resonant with L at operating f. The resonator model is fully specified so shouldn't be hard to simulate.

Some manufacturers provide a reference design with a BOM that details specific information down to the name of their suppliers, the part number, and the values of said passive components. Consumers can assume that this is the "best" known recommended configuration. If it's not listed, then the best approach is to simply ask with details on your desired target specification without necessarily sharing information on your application.
This looks like a Colpitt's Oscillator. You can probably assume the general formula for resonator frequency is
\$ \displaystyle f_r = \frac{1}{2 \pi \sqrt{LC_T}} \$ where \$ C_T\$ is your two capacitors in series.
